# How can I copy files from one directory to another (which is a subdirectory in the original)?

Tags: linux, shell

I'm new to Linux shell script and I'm struggling with a problem. An error pops up telling that the if conditional has too many arguments. What I have to do is basically described on the title, but I've written a code that is not working, what's wrong with it? The original directory is called artists and the subdirectory where the files need to be copied to is called artists_copy.

```
#!/bin/bash
count=0
elem=$(ls)

for file in $elem; do
let count+=1
done

for i in {$count}; do
if [ -e $elem[$i] ]; then
cp $elem[$i] artists_copy
echo "Copied file $elem[$i] to artists_copy"
fi
done
```

Comment: What's wrong with `find /path/to/artists -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec cp -axvp '{}' /path/to/artists_copy \;`?

Comment: Or, if you are in directory `artists`: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec cp -axvp '{}' ./artists_copy \;`

Comment: `man find` for the details.

Comment: The `$elem[$i]` does not make sense to me. `elem` just contains the whole output of the `ls` command, and to this you are adding a string like, i.e. `[1]`. Run your script with `set -x` enabled.

Comment: Why are you using -axvp? And I'm guessing that ' {} ' is where the name of the file goes?